# Best BII for showing particular day tasks in App Actions

Tags: android, android-widget, google-assistant, app-actions

I want to invoke my App widget using Google assistant. My widget is used to show list of tasks of 7 days. So I learned about widget integration using Google assistant from App actions. So my questions is which BII I can use to invoke widget. Please help.

I have seen all BII and got confused to select. In simple words, I want date as param so that I can show that particular date tasks in widget.